# Docker compose using deleted files to create volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm on macOS Big Sur. I had created a simple Docker compose file to create a container with Postgres:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pg:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password 
    ports:
      - "5000:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql
```

Here I'm using the SQL folder in my local folder two copy two files as volumes in the container and run them at the moment the containers run. There are two simple scripts: one to create tables and another to populate them.

**sql/init.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE "Roles"(
    "IdRole" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE "Recipes"(
    "IdRecipe" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE "Comments"(
    "IdComment" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" VARCHAR(50)
);
```

**sql/insert.sql**

```
INSERT INTO "Roles" ("Name")
VALUES ('ROLE_USER'),
('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

The problem I'm issuing is that when I update my init.sql file and delete CREATE TABLE statements, the file inside the container doesn't update. Also, I'm facing the error that docker-compose up always use the old versión of my compose file, I have deleted the volume in my compose file to look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pg:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password 
    ports:
      - "5000:5432"
```

And even there is running init.sql and insert.sql at the moment the container run, I also had deleted the SQL folder and it still creating the volume as if the folder was there running the three CREATE TABLE statements and the inserts at the moments the container compiles. Even I had deleted the folder and created the compose again in a same-named folder and it still created the volume with the three tables and inserts. Is like the container-compose up is using a cached version of the docker-compose file. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: the order of executing the scripts from the ENTRYPOINT is probably alphabetical (default - as you didn't specified how those `.sql` scripts are being triggered at runtime). If you output your script log to `stdout` you should be able to see what is being executed, in which order and how.

Comment: @azbarcea I deleted the files, the composer file don't have to take them anymore for creating volumes, and then when I do docker-compose up --build the inexistent .SQL files still copied to the container.

Comment: you need to delete the volume, otherwise the files will be there: `docker-compose down -v`.